How to use custom package in standalone Lightning Web Runtime Single Page application?
I created standalone LWR SPA with command "npm init lwr".
It is possible to add npm packages in the project with command:
npm install camelCase

then use it in src/modules/app/app.js like this:
import camelCase from 'camelCase'

it works well, but I want to use custom packages that created outside of root dir of lwr-project.
File construct is like this
allRoot
-- lwr-project
---- src
------ modules
-------- app
----------app.js
-- my-package

I linked my-package in the lwr-project with command
lwr-project: npm link . ../my-package
then tried to use in app.js like this:
import my-package from 'my-package'

However, there is an error that could not find module entry with specifier "my-package".
I added the package in lwr.config.json as well, like this:
// lwr.config.json
{
  "lwc": { 
    "modules": [
      { "dir": "$rootDir/src/modules" }, 
      { "name": "my-package", "dir": "../my-pakcage" }
    ]
  },
  ...
}

Moreover, I added the package in the dependencies of the package.json in lwr-project:
...
"dependencies": {
  "my-package": "file:../my-package",
  ...
}

However, there still same issue.
I want to get to know how to use custom packages in standalone LWR SPA.

Is my-pakcage a typo in this question? The modules definition in lwr.config.json looks like it should work without the typo.

@sfdcfox while I move from code to here, I made the typo error. The real package's name is correct. Also, there is no special character such as '-' in real name. For example, package name is 'connector'.
